# How to update multiple mongodb documents with different values based on a key?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I am trying to figure out a way to update multiple documents in a collection with different values based on a key.

**persons collection:**

```
 {
  _id: 1,
  name: "Jackie Chan",
  Country: Australia
},
{
  _id: 2,
  name: "Brad Pitt",
  Country: Russia
},
{
  _id: 3,
  name: "Al Pacino",
  Country: USA
}
```

****Payload:****

```
{
 _id: 1,
 name:"Jackie Chan",
 Country:"China"
}
,{
 _id: 2,
 name:"Brad Pitt",
 Country:"USA"
}
```

persons collection after update:

```
{
      _id: 1,
      name: "Jackie Chan",
      Country: "China"
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: "Brad Pitt",
      Country: "USA"
    },
    {
      _id: 3,
      name: "Al Pacino",
      Country: "USA"
    }
```

SQL equivalent would be :

```
update t1.country = t2.country from persons t1 inner join #temptable t2 on t1._id=t2._id
```

None of the examples mentioned [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) explain how to do it. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: Are you trying to do a bulk update?

Comment: Sort of yes.  If you mean sending multiple documents to db for update at once then yes. @Joe

Comment: I'm not really sure how `Brat Pitt/Russia` + `Brad Pitt/USA` = `Brad Pitt/China`.

Comment: does this help: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/#bulk-write-operations

Comment: @Joe that was a mistake on my part while copy pasting. I have corrected it. 
According to the link that you have shared.. does it mean I will have to have multiple `{ updateOne :{}}` within `bulkWrite()` . As many times as there are records to be updated ?

Comment: If that matches what you're trying to do, it would let you send all of the updates at the same time.

Comment: If there are 200 items that I am sending to the db. I do not want to write `updateOne()` 200 times in my update query. I want tell the db that here is my payload with 200 items.` _id `is the key. Match its values against `_id` column/property of the person collection. And whereever it matches, take the value of country from my payload and update it onto the country property of the collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like bulk write is exactly the right tool.  Simply map the payload array so to make it an array of updates, such as:

```
db.persons.bulkWrite(payload.map( function(p) { 
      return { updateOne:{
                    filter: {_id: p._id},
                    update: {$set: {Country: p.Country}}
      }}
}))
```

Comment: I am not able to get this to work with ObjectId, any ideas?
`await this.db.collection("persons").bulkWrite([{ _id: { "$toObjectId": "5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2d96" }, phone: "123456" }
        , { _id: { "$toObjectId": "5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2da2" }, phone: "1234567" }].map(function (p) {
          return {
            updateOne: {
              filter: { _id: p._id },
              update: { $set: { phone: p.phone } }
            }
          }
        }))`

Comment: ah got it.. i used `new mongo.ObjectID("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2da2") ` and it worked

Comment: I have a question though. I got this in response:
`{
 "acknowledged" : true,
 "deletedCount" : 0,
 "insertedCount" : 0,
 "matchedCount" : 2,
 "upsertedCount" : 0,
 "insertedIds" : {
  
 },
 "upsertedIds" : {
  
 }
}`

Why is it that it says that 0 records were modified?

Comment: The existing document already had the value that the update operation was trying to set.

Comment: what happens if one insert fails?

Answer (score 0):

```
//code when run from mongodb client
> db.persons.find();
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Jackie Chan", "Country" : "China1" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Brad Pitt", "Country" : "Russia1" }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Al Pacino", "Country" : "USA1" }
> var payload=[{_id: 1,name:"Jackie Chan",Country:"China2"},
...              {_id: 2,name: "Brad Pitt",Country: "Russia2"},
...              {_id: 3, name: "Al Pacino",Country: "USA2"}];
> print("payload: ",payload);
payload:  [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
>
> db.persons.bulkWrite(payload.map( function(p) {
...       return { updateOne:{
...                     filter: {_id: p._id},
...                     update: {$set: {Country: p.Country}}
...       }}
... }));
{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "deletedCount" : 0,
        "insertedCount" : 0,
        "matchedCount" : 3,
        "upsertedCount" : 0,
        "insertedIds" : {

        },
        "upsertedIds" : {

        }
}
> db.persons.find();
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Jackie Chan", "Country" : "China2" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Brad Pitt", "Country" : "Russia2" }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Al Pacino", "Country" : "USA2" }
>
```